How to make the Server component whenever the URL parameters changes
Can someone enlighten me on this? is it possible to trigger a re-fetch of data whenever the url parameter changes? because I tried this and it won't work, on context I'm using router.navigate instead of link and also doesn't work. Below is the code for your reference.
// Page.tsx
const Page = async (searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }) => {
  const page = typeof searchParams.page === 'string' ? Number(searchParams.page) : 1
  const collections = await getCollections({ page })

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.categoryWrapper}>
        {collections?.data?.map(collection => <Category data={collection} key={collection?.id} />)}
      </div>
      <Pagination type="collection" />
    </>
  )
}

export default Page
// Pagination.tsx
const Pagination: FC<{ type: 'collection' | 'products' }> = ({ type }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const { collection_length, product_length, default_pageSize } = useAppSelector(state => state.appData.website)
  const initialPage = parseInt(searchParams.get('page') || '1', 10)
  const length = Math.ceil(type === 'collection' ? collection_length / default_pageSize : product_length / default_pageSize)
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(initialPage)

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    if (currentPage < length) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
    }
  }

  const handlePreviousPage = () => {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const current = new URLSearchParams(Array.from(searchParams.entries()))

    if (currentPage === 1) {
      current.delete('page')
    } else {
      current.set('page', currentPage.toString())
    }

    const search = current.toString()
    const query = search ? `?${search}` : ''
    router.push(`${pathname}${query}`)
    router.refresh()
  }, [currentPage, router, pathname, searchParams])

  return (
    <div className={classNames(styles.pagination, roboto.className)}>
      <span onClick={handlePreviousPage}>
        <FaArrowLeft />
      </span>
      {Array.from(Array(length), (_, x) => (
        <span key={x} onClick={() => setCurrentPage(x + 1)}>
          {x + 1}
        </span>
      ))}
      <span onClick={handleNextPage}>
        next
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}


I tried using the link component.
forced adding of url page parameter using router.refresh


You are using searchParams as an argument of the function, while it should be inside an object.
You are not using searchParams correctly in your page component:
interface PageProps {
   searchParams?: {
      page?: string 
   }
}
const Page = async ({ searchParams }: PageProps) => {
   const page = searchParams && typeof searchParams.page === "string" ? Number(searchParams.page) : 1;
   ...
}

This way whenever you call router.push(...), the page will have new searchParams

it works now, thank you.
